# Unable to invoke Java API with ArrayList object from JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am trying to call a Java API that accepts ArraList of Strings from JNI

```
/*My Java Method that needs to be called from JNI*/

public void postArrayListOfStringsToJavaFromJNI(ArrayList<String> list)
{
}

//I am trying to create the methodId like below in JNI to call my Java API postArrayListOfStringsToJavaFromJNI

jmethodID method_id = env->GetMethodID(dmrcallbacks, "postArrayListOfStringsToJavaFromJNI", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V");
```

But I am getting an error

```
11-22 23:22:45.130: E/AndroidRuntime(19189): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='postArrayListOfStringsToJavaFromJNI' signature='(Ljava/lang/Object;)V' in class Lcom/example/JavaSample;
```

Is there any problem with the GetMethodID call that is having "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V" as first parameter for calling the Java API with parameter "ArrayList"

Answer (score 3):

`(Ljava/lang/Object;)V` is the signature of a `void` method taking a single parameter of type `java.lang.Object`, you presumably need `(Ljava/util/ArrayList;)V` instead.